# Replace some letters of string with specific symbol

Tags: c#, string

i have a string like this:

```
string word="HELLO";
```

and clear indexes of string like this:

```
IList<string> clearIndexes = indexes;// for example {2,4}
```

what i want is

```
 *E*L*// the 2th and 4th elements are clear and the other should be shown with *,
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Why is `clearIndexes` a `List<string>` and not a `List<int>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is one approach with the required `List<string>` of indexes

```
string word = "HELLO";
List<string> clearIndexes = new List<string> { "2", "4" };
string result = new string(word.Select((c, i) => !clearIndexes.Contains((i+1).ToString()) ? '*' : c).ToArray());
```

usually a index starts at `0` so i added `(i+1)` to get the result `*E*L*`

Comment: thanx for your response but clearIndexes are list of strings and I cant change the type of it, so I get error.

Comment: @someone, why is it `List<string>` and why position of character to leave un-starred is not index (but `index + 1`) ?

Comment: Slightly better would be `new string(word.Select((c, i) => !clearIndexes.Contains(i+1) ? '*' : c).ToArray());` to avoid converting each `char` to a `string`.

Comment: @Sinatr these indexes are manipulated with a linq query of this:  data.Where(s => s.StartsWith(Word)).Where(s => !s.EndsWith("X")).Select(s=>s.Remove(0,Word.Length)) and the result is list of strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code-snippet:

```
string word = "HELLO";
string[] strIndexes = new string[] { "2", "4" };
//
int[] replacementPositions = Enumerable.Range(1, word.Length) // nonzero-based
    .Where(i => Array.IndexOf(strIndexes, i.ToString()) == -1)
    .ToArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);
for(int i = 0; i < replacementPositions.Length; i++)
    sb[replacementPositions[i] - 1] = '*';

string result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a simple `for`-loop and manipulate the `char[]` returned by `ToCharArray`:

```
char[] chars = word.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    chars[i] = clearIndexes.Contains((i+1).ToString()) ? chars[i] : '*';
word = new string(chars);
```

In general it would be better to use a `List<int>` and to store the index which is zero based.